# Apache 2.2.22 running a Django app shows error "client denied by server configuration"

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a Debian 7.1 amd64 server with apache httpd 2.2.22 and Python 2.7.3 installed, to serve a django app which I've hooked to apache using mod_wsgi and default django `wsgi.py` script. Django is the latest 1.5.4 version with all python package dependencies in a virtualenv managed by `pip` provided with debian.

I've ran `chown -R www-data:www-data` on the entire django and python virtualenv directories to make it work. Apache config for this virtualhost is quite minimal and follows official django guide at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.

I've managed to make it work, except that some clients get apache (not django) 403 Forbidden error page. And apache error logfile for this virtualhost contains lines like this:

```
[client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/django/wsgi.py
```

It works perfectly fine for other clients. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from `mod_evasive` apache module.

I had installed apache mod_evasive for DoS protection, and I did not know that just by installing this module it affects apache and on debian default (non-existing) configuration for this module is quite aggressive for modern service-based web applications.

I created `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.conf` as a default config for this module with higher limits and problem solved.

Comment: You my friend are a scholar, thank you